# Can EKS workers assume preexisting IAM role?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

We run an EKS cluster that's built from a programmatically constructed Cloudformation template. Currently the worker template is close to https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml, but our Resources.NodeInstanceRole.ManagedPolicyArns has some additional user-made policies.

Instead of adding managed policies to this list, we'd like to create an IAM role with whatever policies attached, and then let the EKS workers assume this role. The issue is that we can't find a way to do this in Cloudformation template.

What I believe to be the relevant part of template follows:

```
  NodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - !Ref NodeInstanceRole

  NodeInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
```

Instead of constructing a new IAM::Role (NodeInstanceRole), I imagine there should be a way to reference an existing role's ARN in NodeInstanceProfile. Attempting to change NodeInstanceProfile in the following way results with the following error:

```
  NodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/yyy"
```

```
The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_- (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: xxx)
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [kube2iam](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam)?

Comment: @kichik If I understand correctly, that project addresses the issue of having multiple containers with different permissions on the same node. In our case, we only run one important container per pod (and a single pod per node).

Comment: I'd still go for kube2iam just to save myself the hassle of figuring it out. But specifically for your case, the current error just tells you to use role name instead of ARN.

Comment: You're right, all it needed was the role name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the solution was very simple: NodeInstanceProfile expects role names, rather than ARNs. So in the final version of Cloudformation template, the chunk of code I was referencing was reduced to:

```
NodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - yyy
```